# Redirect inside create.js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was wondering if there was a way to do a redirect inside a js.erb file. I'm converting an app to use ajax so it feels snappier, but my create action leaves the user on the index page.

I could do something like:

```
window.location.replace("/model/@object.id")
```

But I'd prefer to do a full blown redirect_to model_path(@object) if it is possible?

Comment: If you are relying on the browser, then your options are window.location.replace, a form submission (default in rails) or a link.  Depending on how much you are converting your app, you may wish to use a framework like backbone.js to assist with your AJAX calls.

Comment: As this redirect is inside an ajax call (js.erb) javascript is the proper option to do this. So your solution is valid. (redirect_to is on server side while js.erb is ran on client side)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If anyone finds this, here's my code in my List's create.js.erb:

```
<% if @list.errors.any? %>
 //render errors
<% else %>
 $(window.location.replace("/list/<%= @list.id %>"))
<% end %>
```

Comment: This works but be careful of using js styled comments in erb files. They are not always parsed correctly.